# String format C#

Tags: c#, formatting, format, string.format

I want to get the currency value in following format after doing string.format.
I have used several formats but none of them are like what i wanted.

```
Value    After Format
0        $0
123      $123
1234     $1,234
12345    $12,345
```

I have used following code and it works fine.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{00:$#,#}", 12345));
```

But the problem is that when value becomes 0 then it prints just `$` whereas i want to print `$0`

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `00:$#,0` ?

Comment: Did you try Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{00:$0,#}", 12345));

Comment: Just to mention it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#the--section-separator You can even  have positive, zero and negative values be formatted differently in one format expression.

Answer (score 2):

The # in the format string means display a digit if it is not zero.  So when you have a 0 value, then it will not display anything.

So you need to change this to

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{00:$#,0}", mynumber));
```

But you can also use the inbuilt currency string formatting option.

The docs have a whole section on currency formatting
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#CFormatString

So then you can have

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:c}", 99.556551));
```

Or if you don't want any decimals places then

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:C0}", 99.556551));
```

Although this will round the value as well, so it might be better if you control this yourself.

And as reminded by @RufusL below, the `string.format` is not needed in a `Console.Writeline,` so you can also simplify this further;

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:C0}", 99.556551);
```

Comment: @RufusL Yes of course you are right, I just focused on the formatting differences and copy and pasted the rest and I and neglected this.  I will update  to make this obvious.